# Dynamic htaccess handling of subdomain, missing traffic & HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite, traffic

I'm still pretty new to `.htaccess` and RegEx and very frustrated with this but I'm probably over-complicating. Basically:

- `HTTP_HOST` will be one of several domains, and should be preserved as-is including subdomains, **except** `www.` should always be **removed**
- only `domain1` and 'domain2' have SSL, so `HTTPS` should be forced, but any others should be forced to `HTTP`
- if the **first subfolder** after the domain name is `foo`, then rewrite so that `foo` is a subdomain instead of a subfolder.
- after that, **if `foo.` is the subdomain**:

  - **retain** any missing/forbidden folders/file in the visible URL (to be handled later)
  - the actual page for any of these is located at `foo.*.com/index.php`
- missing/forbidden pages **not** on the `foo` subdomain should still be sent to `\index.php` in the root, which I'm currently doing with:

  ```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ /index.php [last,nocase]
  ```

**My attempt:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain1\.ca [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !domain1\.ca [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://foo\.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
RewriteRule "^/foo/(.+)" "%{REQUEST_SCHEME}://foo.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1" [L,NS,QSA,R=301]
```

**Some examples:**

```
incoming url:                               should become:
http://www.domain1.com/foo/blah          => https://foo.domain1.com/blah
https://example.com/foo/blah.html        => http://foo.example.com/blah.html
http://www.domain1.com/foo/index.php/foo => https://foo.domain1.com/foo
https://example.com/blah/blah.html       => http://example.com/blah/blah.html
```

I hope this makes sense (I'm overwhelmed and overdue!) - Thanks!

Comment: _“but any others should be forced to HTTP”_ - “from” where? If there is no valid certificate for any of these, then you are not going to get any incoming HTTPS requests for them in the first place.

Comment: Preserving hostname as-is vs /foo folder - what should happen with `https://bar.example.com/foo/blah.html`? Or are the two situations mutually exclusive?

Comment: @04FS - good thought; I don't expect any traffic to get the url *that*, but if I had to choose I'd prefer to drop the `bar.` and show the url as `https://foo.example.com/blah.html` (but still showing actual content from the `index.html`).  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those rules are a sequential translation based on your question

```
RewriteEngine On

# Remove www from domain, keep scheme (http or https)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}#%{HTTPS}s ^www\.([^#]+)#(?:off|on(s)) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

# force https for {domain1,domain2}
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:domain1|domain2)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

# force http for others
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:domain1|domain2)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

# foo subfolder -> foo subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^foo\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}#%{HTTPS}s ^/foo/([^#]+)#(?:off|on(s)) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%2://foo.%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=302,L]

# hide index.php for foo subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:$|/(.*)) /$1 [R=302,L]

# (internal rewrite) foo subdomain -> foo's root index
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foo/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /foo/index.php [L]

# default rule (root index)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

This is ugly, I agree. But this should work as you expect. It has been tested on a local server and all example tests you showed just passed.

Note: I intentionally used `302` redirects. When everything will be OK on your side, just switch back to `301`.

Comment: Awesome, sorry for the delayed response but it looks great so far. Thanks @Justin!

Comment: Hey @Justin, actually it's not forcing the domain to HTTPS that I need it to.  in the section `# force https for {domain1,domain2}` (and the following section) could the `on` and `off` be reversed?  Also should I replace `domain1` with only the SLD (`domain1`) and not the TLD (`.com`)?

Comment: What do you mean by `could the on and off be reversed`? Anyway, yes, this is only the SLD part.